# How to call an URI upon @click?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, onclick, vue-component, uri

In a SPA web application I need to call a URI as the reaction to a click on an icon.

I can successfully do this as part of a `<a>` anchor:

```html
<a href="obsidian://open?vault=Obsidian&file=test" class="q-mr-md">
  <q-icon name="open_in_new"></q-icon>
</a>
```

I would like to ask whether it is possible to do a similar action for a button. The code below does not work (the URI is not called)

```
<button square icon="open_in_new" @click="obsidian://open?vault=Obsidian&file=test"></button>
```

What I actually need is a way to say *"run the URI with the default handler" as a response to a `@click`*

Comment: Maybe with a `$router.push`?

Comment: @kissu: this could be an idea. The route will actually be added as a virtual one (after `/#/` - this is a SPA) but I will make some tests. Thanks.

Comment: @kissu: setting `window.location.href` to the URI was the solution. I flagged it as duplicate.